# WPF Navigate from frame in window to Usercontrol and pass parameters to it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, parameters, user-controls

I have a modern window in WPF/C# application, in which I added a modern frame:

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Style="{StaticResource EmptyWindow}">

<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<Menu x:Name="menu" Height="62" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <MenuItem x:Name="miHome" Header="Home" Click="MenuItem_Home" IsChecked="True" Width="60" FontSize="14" />
        <MenuItem x:Name="miClients" Header="Clients"  FontSize="14" Click="MenuItem_Clients" Width="65"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="miSuppliers" Header="Suppliers" FontSize="14"  Click="MenuItem_Suppliers" Width="81"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="miReports" Header="Reports" FontSize="14"  Click="MenuItem_Reporting" Width="71"/>
    </Menu>
    <mui:ModernFrame Margin="0,75,10,10" x:Name="frame">

    </mui:ModernFrame>
</Grid>
```

I have MenuItems in my application, when I click on Suppliers item, I fill the frame with a usercontrol, like this:

```
frame.Source = new Uri("/Pages/Suppliers.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Where Suppliers.xaml design is:

```
<UserControl
             x:Class="MyApp.LinksBar.Suppliers"
             xmlns:MyApp="clr-namespace:MyApp" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"  
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="575" d:DesignWidth="905">
    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid  Name="Grid">
        <mui:ModernButton x:Name="btnmakePayment" Content="Make Payment" Click="btnMakePayment_Click" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I click on "Make Payment" button, I navigate to another UserControl (MakePayment.xaml):

```
private void btnMakePayment_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute(new Uri("/Actions/MakePayment.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
}
```

MakePayment.xaml design is:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Actions" x:Class="MyApp.Actions.MakePayment" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:MyApp="clr-namespace:MyApp" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Loaded="MakePayment_Loaded"
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="866" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource makePaymentViewSource}" Name="Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Total"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    // More design code here ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Here comes my question:**
I need to **pass parameters from Suppliers UserControl to MakePayment UserControl**.
How to programmatically pass the parameters in Suppliers and read them in MakePayment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can bind one to the other, that is what you should be doing. By far, the easiest way to make two UserControls "communicate" (or share properties that both can do stuff with) is to define a DependencyProperty on each and bind them two-way.

This way, both always have access to the same value and both can do stuff with it.

Take my own control as an example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.MasterContainerControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControls"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Name="masterContainerControl">
    <local:ContainerControl SomeProperty="{Binding ElementName=masterContainerControl, Path=SomeProperty}">
        <local:ContainerControl.Another>
            <local:AnotherControl SomeProperty="{Binding ElementName=masterContainerControl, Path=SomeProperty"/>
        </local:ExplorerBase.AddressBar>
        <local:ContainerControl.Some>
            <local:SomeControl SomeProperty="{Binding ElementName=masterContainerControl, Path=SomeProperty"/>
        </local:ContainerControl.Some>  
    </local:ContainerControl>
</UserControl>
```

This, of course, all assumes `MasterContainerControl`, `ContainerControl`, `AnotherControl`, and `SomeControl` all have a DependencyProperty called `SomeProperty`, and then the bindings seal the deal.

Note: Make sure the default values are defined in MasterContainerControl because those will override the values MasterContainerControl binds to.

If I misunderstood your issue, please let me know.